# Update a table using partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible that we can use two partition while updating a table?

For example, i try to do something like that but giving me error.

```
update student PARTITION (ma_stu_class1, ma_stu_class2)
set branch = 'R'||100;
```

Please let me know if there is any way to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating partitioned table oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847652/updating-partitioned-table-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use multiple partitions in select as well as update. Instead you can use below query.

```
MERGE INTO student S
USING (SELECT * FROM student PARTITION(ma_stu_class1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM student PARTITION(ma_stu_class2)) S1
ON (S.CONNON_COLUMN = S1.COMMON_COLUMN)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET 
branch = 'R'||100;
```

UNION ALL same table with multiple partitions and using MERGE function you can update the table

Answer (score 0):

You can't update multiple partitions like that, as per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#BABGGJCE) - if you could, there would be an arrow coming out of the right hand side of the `partition` inside the `PARTITION (partition)` part of the diagram that would take you back to the left hand side of the `partition` via a `,` - similar to that of the top half of the update_set_clause diagram.

Instead, you have to use the partition key in your where clause, e.g. if your key is on, say, col1 and col2, you would do:

```
update student
set    branch = 'R'||100
where  (col1, col2) in (('class1', 'a'), ('class2', 'b'));
```